# Why is a complete binary tree most suited for heap implementation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, computer-science, heap

I could not figure out why complete binary tree is most suited for mplementing heap? why we cannot use full binary tree? WHy complete binary tree is the most suited for heap implementation?

Comment: _"why we cannot use full binary tree"_? Have you read/understood the difference between between a full and a complete binary tree? If so, can you explain why are you suggesting a full binary tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Full binary trees for heaps?

A [full binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) is not necessarily well-balanced. For instance, this is a full binary tree:

```
             1
            / \
           2   3
          / \
         4   5
        / \
       6   7
      / \
     8   9
    / \
  10   11
```

In general, a full binary tree where *any* right child is also a leaf, has a height that is O(), more precisely, (−1)/2. This will be problematic for heaps, which rely on the tree being well balanced to keep its insert/delete operations within a time complexity of O(log).

Secondly, full binary trees always have an *odd* number of nodes (except when they are empty). This already makes them impractical, as obviously heaps should be able to have *even* sizes too.

#### Other alternative

However, binary heaps do not *have* to be complete binary trees. That is only required when their implementation is the well-known array-based one. But one could also implement a binary heap with an AVL tree, which is not necessarily a complete binary tree, but which still keeps the tree balanced and will have the same time complexities for the heap operations. But since the overhead of the pointer management is larger than working with indices in an array, the array representation leads to faster operations.

#### Why complete?

The choice for a complete binary tree comes into play when the implementation is array-based and not an explicit node-pointer representation. When you fill an array with values in *level-order*, and don't allow for *gaps* in the array (unused slots), then it follows that the tree is complete. Although you could imagine an array that allows for gaps, this would be an inferior choice, as it wastes space, with no gain to compensate for it.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, **it is not possible to create a heap structure without it being *tightly packed*.** Every item in the array has a position in the binary tree, and this position comes from the array index.

Also, **it has several advantages** like the following:

- Some operations of the heap have a time complexity of `O(lgn)` where `n` is the height of the tree, keeping the height of the tree at a minimum allows us to keep the time required for these operations at a minimum.
- All the items of the complete binary tree are stored in a contiguous manner in an array so random access is possible by keeping the heap as a complete binary tree
- The completeness ensures that there is a well-defined and efficient way to determine the new root when an element is removed, not using a complete structure would mean losing this advantage (which is why you should use heap in the first place).

Comment: You're mixing two concepts here - "balanced" which guarantees the height is O(log(n)), and "complete" which guarantees the tree can be represented by an array. They are not equivalent: "complete" implies "balanced", but the converse is not true.

Comment: Every complete binary tree is balanced, hence the first advantage I list is true. My answer explains the advantages of using a complete tree, not the advantages
 we can have "only" using complete trees.